# How can I find a file within a specific directory name?

Tags: linux, find, command-line-interface

So I need to find all files in /home/ with a file name of "options.php".

```
find . -name "options.php"
```

When 'in home', that will find all options.php files, however, I want to only find all options.php files when they are in /public_html/.
So in other words, it should ignore all other 'options.php' files found.
eg, positive/show results:

```
/home/usr1/public_html/options.php
/home/usr2/public_html/options.php
```

eg, shouldnt show me:

```
/home/usr1/public_html/wp-admin/options.php
/home/usr2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/whatever/options.php
```

Comment: install this https://github.com/Avinash-Raj/pls and then run `cd /home/usr1/public_html & pls 'options.php' `

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a pattern via `-path` option as follows:

```
find /home/ -path '*/public_html/options.php'
```

For a more flexible pattern use `-regex` which accepts a regular expression applied on the whole path. But in this particular case `-regex` has no advantage over `-path`:

```
find /home/ -regex '.*/public_html/options.php'
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the desired results from the found results with `grep`.

```
find . -name "options.php" | grep 'public_html/options.php'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While correct - Ruslan's option above is much faster.

Comment: This will also find matches in folders called "public_html" located further down in the hierarchy...

Comment: You mean that `public_html/xxx/public_html/options.php`? Right? But there is no such path.@arkascha

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` utility is much better suited for this task:

```
ls -1 /home/*/public_html/options.php
```

If you want to process the result list and do *not* want to have an error message or warning in case no such files are found, then simply redirect the error output of the command:

```
ls -1 /home/*/public_html/options.php 2>/dev/null
```

---

An alternative using the `find` utility would be:

```
find /home -path "*/public_html/options.php"
```

Or, if you want to prevent matches in folders called "public_html" further down in the hierarchy:

```
find /home -path "/home/*/public_html/options.php"
find /home -maxdepth 3 -path "*/public_html/options.php"
```

Comment: /bin/ls: cannot access /home/*/public_html/options.php: No such file or directory

Comment: @SupaMonkey That is strange, I do _not_ get that response, _except_ obviously if there actually are no such files... Maybe you want to redirect the error output?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the depth of find:
`find . -maxdepth N`, this way It should only find options.php in your desired folder.